# Using nested div id's to list a specific range of elements in Jsoup

Tags: java, html, web-scraping, jsoup

I am trying to scrape specific information from a page, but I only want to list a set range of items from it.

Here is a sample of what I'm working with:

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-12">
    <form action="nutritiveReport.aspx?locationNum=09&dtdate=11%2f01%2f2022" method="post" id="full_menu_form">
      <input type="hidden" name="Action" id="action_indicator" value>
      <div id="full_menu">
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs responsive" id="full_menu_tabs" role="tablist">...</ul>
        <div class="tab-content responsive" id="full_menu_content">
          <div class="tab-pane fade active show" id="meal_1_content" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="meal_1_tab">
            <div class="card">
              <div class="card-header" id="menu_group_heading_1">
                <h5 class="mb-0">
                  <a class="btn btn-link" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#menu_group_content_1"
                    aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="menu_group_content_1">
                    " Freshen's "
                  </a>
                </h5>
              </div>
              <div id="menu_group_content_1" class="collapse show" aria-labelledby="menu_group_heading_1" style>
                <div class="card-body">
                  <div class="row recipe_container">...</div>
                  <div class="row recipe_container">...</div>
                  <div class="row recipe_container">...</div>
                  <div class="row recipe_container">...</div>
                  <div class="row recipe_container">...</div>
                  <div class="row recipe_container">...</div>
```

There are many different cards on this site, each holding a `"card-header"` with ID `"menu_group_heading_#"` (where # represents a different number) and each containing their own set of `"row_recipe_container"` `div`s in a `card-body`.

I'm trying to only scrape the set of `row_recipe_container` `div`s found in a specific menu group heading. So, for example, if the input menu group heading was "Olive Garden", I'd only want to print the data in the `row_recipe_container`s for Olive Garden, and not the rest of the page.

I've figured out how to print the menu headings and recipe data for *every* card on the site. Here's some pseudocode to demonstrate how I want it to behave:

```
// menu headings: Olive Garden, Chipotle, Red Lobster
if menu heading == "Olive Garden" {
    System.out.println(recipe data ONLY for Olive Garden);
}
```

I only understand how to print all of the recipe data and menu headings from the page. For example, I have the following which prints out *only* the menu headings:

```java
final Document doc = Jsoup.connect(pageUrl).get();
for (Element row : doc.select("div[id*=menu_group_heading]")) {
    String names = row.select("div[id*=menu_group_heading]").text();
    System.out.println(names);
}
```

I have similar code that prints out only the recipe data under all menu headers.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: What's the URL of the webpage you're trying to scrape?

Answer (score 0):

So you need to:

1. iterate the tree to look for the card that contains your desired menu heading string
2. store the `data-target` attribute of the `a` element in your `card-header`
3. query your document for elements that:

   - are children of the element with the id equal to the one found in (2.)
   - contain both classes `row` and `recipe_container`

Something like this should work:

```java
// Document doc = ...
String inputMenuHeading = "Freshen's";
String targetId =
    doc.select("[class=card-header], [id*=menu_group_heading]")
       .stream()
       .filter(e -> e.html().contains(inputMenuHeading))
       .findFirst().get()
       .select("a").attr("data-target");
        
Elements result = doc.select(String.format("%s .row, .recipe_container", targetId));
System.out.println(result);
```